# reverse animate in infinite mode

Tags: react-native, infinite, react-native-animatable

I am use react-native-animatable ,  when use zoomIn animate, After zooming once, it zoomOut then zooming in , how can ignore reverse in infinite mode

```
<Animatable.View
            iterationDelay={2000}
            animation="zoomIn"
            iterationCount={'infinite'}
            direction="alternate"
            style={[ {height:200,width:200,alignSelf:'center' , alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' ,opacity:0  }]}
        >
```

[gif my animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHESF.gif)

Comment: you want only zoomIn animation?

Comment: yes did you use react-native-animatable @Jigar

Comment: if you use iterationCount={'infinite'} what will animate after zoom in ?  what we animate infinite times?